# MATLAB - Interpolate from irregular grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I tried to interpolate DATA (of size NixMi) from irregular polar grid (Xi and Yi of size NixMi) to regular grid (Xr and Yr of size NrxMr).

I tried with `interpn(Xi,Yi,DATA,Xr,Yr)`

But it didn't work and I received the error message : "Error using griddedInterpolant - Data is not valid NDGRID format".

I think this is because my entry grid has to be strictly monotonic.

I tried with scatteredInterpolant, griddata and griddatan but still a failure.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: "I tried with scatteredInterpolant, griddata and griddatan but still a failure." Well, that is how you do it, so probably you did it wrong?

Comment: I don't know but the things is that Xi is the norm and Yi is the phase. So their are totally irregular (Xi looks like a concentric circle).

Comment: Please post a [mcve], that is extremely important information that you just gave in a comment, instead in the question. By your current description it seems that you may have a regular grid, just not a *cartesian* regular grid. `griddata` is from when your data is scattered in a cartesian grid, not for other spaces.